# How to pass Image from from TableViewCell to UIImage

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimage, swift3

[My segues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ptyC.png)I am trying to figure out if there is a way for me to pass image in the cell that I select to a new `UIImageView` in a completely different view controller. I dont fully understand how the segue works and after hours of deliberation I have not yet fully found a solution. I have been able to display my images in the `tableview`, but I want to send the selected image to the `UIImageView` for a bigger view of the picture. I currently have 2 VCs for this. The first of them is called TableView

```
import UIKit

class TableView: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    @IBAction func toImage(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ImageView", sender: self)
    }

    // Properties
    var imagesDirectoryPath:String!
    var images:[UIImage]!
    var titles:[String]!

    @IBAction func choosePhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            print("Library selected")
        }else{
            print("No cam here!")
        }

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView!.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"CellID")

        images = []

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        // Get the Document directory path
        let documentDirectorPath:String = paths[0]
        // Create a new path for the new images folder
        imagesDirectoryPath = documentDirectorPath + "/ImagePicker"
        var objcBool:ObjCBool = true
        let isExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagesDirectoryPath, isDirectory: &objcBool)
        // If the folder with the given path doesn't exist already, create it
        if isExist == false{
            do{
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: imagesDirectoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }catch{
                print("Something went wrong while creating a new folder")
            }
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func refreshTable(){
        do{
            images.removeAll()
            titles = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imagesDirectoryPath)
            for image in titles{
                let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: imagesDirectoryPath + "/\(image)")
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                images.append(image!)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }catch{
            print("Error")
        }
    }


    //MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        // Save image to Document directory
        var imagePath = Date().description
        imagePath = imagePath.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        imagePath = imagesDirectoryPath + "/\(imagePath).png" //this would change depending on the name of the image
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        _ = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: imagePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in
            self.refreshTable()
        }
    }

    //MARK: UITableView DataSource
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID")

        cell?.imageView?.image = images[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ImageView", sender: images[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var secondVC : ImageView = segue.destination as! ImageView

        //secondVC.fullView = imagesDirectoryPath[IndexPath.row]
    }



}
```

This is my `ImageView`, where I want my image from the cell to appear.

```
import UIKit

class ImageView:ViewController{

    @IBOutlet var fullView: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage = UIImage()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.fullView.image = self.selectedImage //Assign selected Image here




    }
    //segue via a button
    @IBAction func toTable(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TableView", sender: self)

    }


}
```

So is there any way that I could pass the existing image to an `UIImageView` in an another VC. I combed through all over Google, but I cant seem to get figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: check your class declaration inheritance. `class ImageViewController : UIViewController {...}`

Comment: I changed the ImageView to SecondViewController and added UIViewController instead of ViewController, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Look at the class declaration on the vc's nib in the storyboard file. It needs to be `SecondViewController` also

Comment: All of the declarations look correct. I double checked all of of the identifiers but it still gives me the same error. Let me know if you want to see any screenshots of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard file make sure the custom class is set to `SecondViewController` on the segue destination's nib:

[image]

Comment: Yup, I changed that when I changed the name of the ImageView to SecondViewController. The error points to this specific line: ' let secondVC : SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController ' .

Comment: drop a breakpoint right there and in the console `po type(of: segue.destination)`

Comment: It tells me that it "Could not cast value of type 'Lab9.ViewController' (0x102682bc0) to 'Lab9.SecondViewController' (0x102682af8)." ViewController is a different viewcontroller and I dont understand why its popping up here.

Comment: Is there more than one segue in your storyboard file?

Comment: I got the result: Lab9.ViewController. Thats weird because its supposed to go to SecondViewController

Comment: Yes, I am using buttons and a UINavigationController to go from page to page.

Comment: Since your implementation seems to be performing a segue multiple times simultaneously, it seems to me that it's trying to perform one that's still pointed at `ViewController`

Comment: How would I be able to fix that?

Comment: Don't call `perfomSegue` in the swift file

Comment: A segue created in a storboard file will be perfomed automatically without needing to be called in the swift file

Comment: Is there more than one segue in the storyboard file?

Comment: Yes. So I basically have a button on the first view controller that sends the user to the table and there in the table the user selects a picture and displays it in the table view and when I click on the tableview the app is supposed to segue me into the second vc and in the second vc I have a button that that enable me to come back to the tableview so the user can pick another picture and go back to the second vc. I also added my segues as a picture named "My segues" at the very beginning of my question on the top of this page.

Comment: Ah, I did not see the hyperlink to the image. That's very helpful. Okay, so your root vc is a NavigationController with ViewController embedded as its root vc. Because of this you can use `show` segues instead of `modal presentation` segues which lets the nav controller handle the back button (or "popping the controllers"). Your segue OUT of the tableViewController points BACK to ViewController when it's expecting to go to SecondViewController, so you need to point that one to SecondViewController instead. Remove the other back segues after converting to show segues.

Comment: Woo-Hoo. Thanks a bunch! I had no idea that segues back to previous view weren't necessary. Now I can finally go to bed!

Comment: Glad it worked :) Yup, pops (for shows/pushes) and dismissals (for modals) handle the reversing. Apple has written a lot of great guides to explain how Cocoa works. Here's the one on VC Hierarchies: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW1 Keep in mind that's reference material. Don't try to memorize it all, haha.